# node api served on localhost:3000 or ip_address:3000, not accessible through android app from device (not emulator)

Tags: android, ios, node.js, angular, nativescript

Build an Android app (using nativescript-angular), and running on device that is connected to same wifi (also connected to development machine by usb with debugger on).

I initially tried using chrome port forwarding (while device was connected to development machine by usb) and tried localhost:3000/api/test.

> 1. It worked on chrome browser of android
> 2. It didn't work on android app that calls that route.

I tried connecting the laptop and the device to the same wifi, and found the ip of the laptop. Then tried 192.168.0.103:3000/api/test.

> 1. It worked on chrome browser
> 2. It didn't work on android app that calls that route.

Tried the same on an ios emulator. Used path http://localhost:3000/api/test 
Still getting the same error.

> ERROR: CONSOLE LOG file:///app/shared/user/user.service.js:37:20:
>   trying: http://localhost:3000/api/users/test CONSOLE LOG
>   file:///app/shared/user/user.service.js:63:20: error: Response with
>   status: 200  for URL: null

I use the code:

```
return this.http.post(
  Config.apiUrl + "api/users/register",
  {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  },
  { headers: this.getCommonHeaders() }
).pipe(
  map(response => {
    this.setToken(response.headers.toJSON()['x-auth'][0])
    return response.json()
  }),
  catchError(this.handleErrors)
);
```

What's going on, in the mobile app? It's not hitting the server end-point.

Comment: Is the website HTTPS? Could be a certificate issue. Are you able to hit the endpoint in the browser of the android device?

Comment: ignore my previous comment, that was for hitting the db. what command are you using to run your app because I am guessing you are using `ng serve`? try running this in your command prompt `ng serve --host 192.168.0.103 --disable-host-check -o`

Comment: Yeah @rickjerrity ... Chrome browser of the phone ...

Comment: If you can hit it through the browser of the device and get a response, it is either a certificate issue because Android uses a strict root CA store or invalid request code. Can you clarify what didn't work about the call? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: It's built through nativescript, so I console.logged the error-
JS: error: Response with status: 200  for URL: null
(Still working on chrome of device)

Comment: @rhavelka - Im' using nodemon to run the app. There is no angular-cli for the backend.